# Permission denied (publickey) - new laptop

Tags: permissions, ssh

I have setup an ubuntu Oracle instance two years ago. I have configured SSH Key-Based Authentication, generating the ssh private key from Oracle and saved it in a local (windows) folder. I have used it to access via mobaxterm successfully from my Windows PC (Advanced ssh settings-use private key).
Now I have a new Windows laptop (besides the old one). I want to access via mobaxterm the same way, and I copied the generated file from the old laptop to the new one. I setup my mobaxterm the same way, with the copied file, and mobaxterm console says:

Permission denied (publickey)

How can I solve it?
NB
I don't want to enable password access!

Comment: "Permission denied (publickey)" means that the wrong key was presented to the Ubuntu system. That ends Ubuntu's involvement. How to configure your Windows system so  mobaxterm sends the correct key seems like a Windows or mobaxterm support question.

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details; two years ago may have meant it was a product/release that isn't supported any longer, or is; but without details we won't know. I'd go with prior comment though (*we don't have details on the Ubuntu system anyway*)